# Rails timezone changes when increasing timestamp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, recurring-events

I am trying to create recurring events with based on a gap in the timestamp and experiencing what seems to be odd behavior: if I continue to increase a timestamp by a weekly gap (604800 seconds), Rails seems to change the timezone on me.

```
t = Time.new(2015, 2, 22, 14, 0)
 => 2015-02-22 14:00:00 -0500 
gap = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
 => 604800 
newt = t + gap
 => 2015-03-01 14:00:00 -0500 
newt + gap
 => 2015-03-08 15:00:00 -0400
```

What am I doing wrong? Or what am I doing to cause this timezone issue?

Comment: Daytime saving change in your local timezone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the time zone changes from standard time to daylight savings time on March 8th, 2015.

Comment: One way would be to start with a time in UTC: `t = Time.new(2015, 2, 22, 14, 0).utc`

Comment: The time I am starting with is in UTC, however, when I increase the timestamp by what would be 1 week, if we "gain or lose an hour" in our timezone, it messes up the time that it should be.

Comment: I wonder if this is Rails version specific. Under Rails 4.2.0, as long as I start with a timezone that does not have DST then the calculation is correct even when passing through DST boundaries.

Comment: I'll check my version of Rails and update you on this.